# The vomiTing and omiTTing Paradox

Tags: word-usage

I guess it's an unanswerable question:

Why "vomit" + "ing" = "vomiTing"

BUT

"vomit" - "v" + "ing" = "omiTTing"

Answer (score 4):

In general, if the stress is on the first syllable, the word gets only one consonant + -ing, but otherwise the consonant is doubled, thus vomit doesn't double, but omit does. However, this "rule" has many exceptions, in particular there are many two-syllable verbs with accented first syllable which double in British English, but not in American, e.g. travel, counsel, marvel etc.

[Why do some words have double consonants while others have only one?](http://a4esl.org/q/h/9807/km-doubles.html)